# Use X509Certificate without requiring passphrase

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I have a certificate that I need to use in order to access a web service. The problem is that whenever I try to use the X509 certificate it asks for a passphrase (PIN). Is there any way of providing the passphrase directly, without it popping up the same window every time?

[image: I hate this window]

The certificate uses a dongle made by Oberthur Technologies, if it's of any help. Here's the code I use to get the certificate:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("MY",StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

if(collection.Count != 0)
    userCert = collection[0]; // everything's ok up to here
```

And here's where I use the certificate:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
req.ClientCertificates.Add(userCert); // add the certificate I just got
// ...
WebResponse ret = req.GetResponse(); // here's where it asks me for my passphrase
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate's private key is stored on the Oberthur token.  It is enforcing the user to enter the PIN to gain access to certificates private key.  This is by design and cannot be overridden.

Comment: +1 thanks for the information. This is not what I wanted to hear, unfortunately. Is this done by Oberthur or is this a standard feature of all tokens (asking for the pin)? I'm asking this because I have to use this in an app that gets called from the console by others. If they have to enter the pin every time the app is run, it would be awful.

Comment: This is a standard feature of a token.  Normally, you can configure the token software to only prompt the first time and then allow x minutes of access to the certificate before prompting again.  Sorry but I do not know the details of the Oberthur implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for a way to do it with managed code but haven't yet found one.
In the past I have just called the CAPI function CryptSetProvParam with option PP_SIGNATURE_PIN and the PIN as the data.  This prevents the CSP from prompting the user for a PIN.  It's kinda hard for a system service to enter that PIN :)

So, you will have to pinvoke CryptSetProvParam to do it.